# Roots of exceptional complex reflection groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-algebras, reflection-groups

I am looking to do a case-by-case check of a conjecture I have about Shephard groups, which are a subclass of complex reflection groups. These were classified by Shephard and Todd and there is one infinite class and 34 exceptional cases. I have shown the result for the groups $G(r,1,n)$. To finish checking my conjecture, I need to know the "roots" associated to each of the exceptional groups (well, I guess just the Shephard groups).

Let me elaborate: Each complex reflection group is generated by generalized reflections, which are elements of $GL(V)$ with finite order that fix a hyperplane point-wise. I need to know what these hyperplanes are.

I'm looking for a list along the lines of what occurs in the "Plates" of Bourbaki's book on Lie Groups, or in Section 2.10 of Humphrey's book on *real* reflection groups.

Thanks.

Comment: Though I haven't gone far enough into this to know what's really important, I'd suggest you look at the softcover 2009 Cambridge Univ. Press. book by G.I. Lehrer and D.E. Taylor, *Unitary Reflection Groups*.    They introduce "root systems" in appropriate generality at the end of Chapter 1, and later they develop detailed information based on the classification.     What I don't know is whether you will easily locate the data you need, though they have a lot of tables at the end of the book.

Comment: There is an ongoing project of Broué-Corran-Michel on roots for complex reflection groups. There is apparently no preprint yet but here are notes from a talk of Broué on the topic https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.broue/Serge2015.pdf 
I have not idea if this helps or not for your problem, but it might be worth having a look and maybe write an email to Jean Michel.

Comment: In "Congruence classes of presentations for the complex reflection groups $G(m, p, n)$", Paragraph 1.4, Shi provides explicit representatives for the root system of $G(m,p,n)$.